# Gradle assembleMyAppDebug FileNotFoundException manifest_keep.txt

Tags: android, gradle, continuous-integration, android-gradle-plugin

Once I run `gradle assembleMyAppDebug` I get the following error:

```
:app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForMyAppDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForMyAppDebug'.
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/jenkins/workspace/my-app/app/build/intermediates/multi-dex/myapp/debug/manifest_keep.txt (No such file or directory)
```

I could not find indication of what can be the error.

The result from `gradle --version`:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 3.5
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2017-04-10 13:37:25 UTC
Revision:     b762622a185d59ce0cfc9cbc6ab5dd22469e18a6

Groovy:       2.4.10
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015
JVM:          1.8.0_121 (Oracle Corporation 25.121-b13)
OS:           Linux 4.9.20-11.31.amzn1.x86_64 amd64
```

**Update:**

I've tried to run `gradle clean` before `gradle assembleMyAppDebug` and then the error changes to:

```
Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly (it may have been killed or may have crashed)
```

The job is running inside a Docker container on AWS ECS on Jenkins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried a lot of different configurations and solutions. In the end seems the real issue was related to the available memory and CPU for the container. Once I updated both parameters from 1GB to 3GB memory and from 1 CPU to 2 CPUs it started working perfectly.

Comment: What do you mean by **container**?  I am on a Macbook Pro.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky the last statement on the question is "The job is running inside a Docker container on AWS ECS on Jenkins."